# Issue with HTTP Handlers and IIS7

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, httphandler

I've been developing a custom HTTP handler. Using the new web.config `<httphandlers>` section for ASP.NET 4.0 and IIS7, this works great on my development machine.

However, when I upload the code to my shared-hosting account, I get a 500 server error. I called my hosting company and they said the server was reporting an error about a web.config setting being detected that does not apply to integrated pipeline mode.

When he switched IIS from integrated to classic mode, the home page then loads okay but my routed pages all report a 403 server error.

I'm pretty sure I need integrated mode in order for the `<httphandlers>` section to work, but I am definitely not an IIS/admin guy. Does anyone have any idea what the problem might be or what I can try next?

**EDIT:** The bulk of my updated web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        [...]
    </connectionStrings>
    <appSettings>
        [...]
    </appSettings>
    <system.web>
        <httpHandlers>
            <add verb="*" path="*.zip" type="BlackBelt.ZipHttpHandler"/>
        </httpHandlers>
        <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    </system.web>
    <system.webServer>
        <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
        <handlers>
            <add verb="*" path="BlackBelt.ZipHttpHandler" name="BlackBelt.ZipHttpHandler" type="BlackBelt.ZipHttpHandler"/>
        </handlers>
        <!-- Redirect domain.com to www.domain.com -->
        <rewrite>
            <rules>
                <clear/>
                <rule name="WWW Rewrite" enabled="true">
                    <match url="(.*)"/>
                    <conditions>
                        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" negate="true" pattern="^www\.([.a-zA-Z0-9]+)$"/>
                    </conditions>
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.{HTTP_HOST}/{R:0}" appendQueryString="true" redirectType="Permanent"/>
                </rule>
            </rules>
        </rewrite>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: handlers in IIS7 integrated mode goes under <system.webServer/handlers>, not <system.web/httpHandlers>

Comment: and no, without any more specific error messages its next to impossible to say what the problem could be.

Comment: @Pauli: Thanks--I made some edits after reading http://forums.asp.net/p/1500622/3548870.aspx, which indicated I needed both sections but I'm getting the same results. I've posted the bulk of my web.config file.

Comment: Oddly enough, I commented out the system.web/httphandlers section. And I see that some ZIP files go through the handler while others do not.

Comment: Actually, it may have been some caching issues. It may actually be working. Thanks for the tip. I'm open to suggestions with my web.config file though.

Comment: you never need both sections... only one of them! though, if you use ie. the ASP.NET Development Server (Cassini) bundled with VS it will only recognize <system.web/httpHandlers> which is pretty annoying. i can recommend using IIS Express instead for developing  (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=abc59783-89de-4adc-b770-0a720bb21deb)

Comment: Thanks @Pauli, with your nudge it seems to be working great. Yes, that is a frustration when you get something working on the dev machine only to find that's not what's needed on the server. Will consider IIS Express.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Thanks to Pauli, I was able to figure this out. Although `<system.web><httpHandlers>` is the section I must change to get it to work when running from Visual Studio, `<system.webServer><handlers>` is the section I must modify to get it to work when running on the server, which is running IIS7.

I've received email asking exactly how I resolved this. I've written an article that describes the exact steps and presents my code. If anyone wants to see this article, it is available at http://www.blackbeltcoder.com/Articles/asp/writing-a-custom-http-handler-in-asp-net.